# Template deduction with leading pack expansion fails on GCC 4.8.2 x86 (devtoolset-2) only

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, variadic-templates, devtoolset

Here's an MCVE from some template metahackery in my C++11 project:

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo {};

template <typename... T>
void expect(std::function<void(const T&)>&&... onSuccess)
{
    expect<T...>(
        std::forward<std::function<void(const T&)>>(onSuccess)...,
        0,
        [](){}
    );
}

template <typename... T>
void expect(
  std::function<void(const T&)>&&... onSuccess,
  const time_t timeout,
  std::function<void()>&& onExpiry
)
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    expect<Foo>([=](const Foo&) {}, 42u, [=](){});
}
```

It builds fine in GCC 6.1<sup>([using Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50207860715a538c))</sup>, GCC 4.8.5 and GCC 4.8.2 x86_64<sup>(using [GodBolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org))</sup>, but when I plug it into my development environment (which is GCC 4.8.2 via devtoolset-2 on CentOS 6 x86) I get errors:

```
[root@localhost ~]# g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:27:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘expect(main()::__lambda1, unsigned int, main()::__lambda2)’
   expect<Foo>([=](const Foo&) {}, 42u, [=](){});
                                               ^
test.cpp:27:47: note: candidates are:
test.cpp:6:6: note: template<class ... T> void expect(std::function<void(const T&)>&& ...)
 void expect(std::function<void(const T&)>&&... onSuccess)
      ^
test.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:27:47: note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<void(const T&)>’ and ‘unsigned int’
   expect<Foo>([=](const Foo&) {}, 42u, [=](){});
                                               ^
test.cpp:16:6: note: template<class ... T> void expect(std::function<void(const T&)>&& ..., time_t, std::function<void()>&&)
 void expect(
      ^
test.cpp:16:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:27:47: note:   cannot convert ‘<lambda closure object>main()::__lambda1{}’ (type ‘main()::__lambda1’) to type ‘time_t {aka long int}’
   expect<Foo>([=](const Foo&) {}, 42u, [=](){});

[root@localhost ~]# g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-i686-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-i686-redhat-linux/cloog-install --with-mpc=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.2-20140120/obj-i686-redhat-linux/mpc-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i686 --build=i686-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC)
```

I can work around this by moving `onSuccess` to after `timeout` and `onExpiry` in the second overload, but I think the original ordering is easier for developers to use and would rather keep it if I can.

So is there any other way?

*And, for bonus points, what's actually going on?*

Comment: If ever, you can reproduce with gcc 4.8.1 on godbolt.

Comment: @Holt: Heh, good spot.

Comment: Also, it compiles with gcc 4.8.1 (godbolt) if you invert the declaration of the `expect` functions.

Comment: @Holt: I love you! Wanna write an answer?

Comment: I can't really explain it but sure... ;)

Comment: OT - These `&&` looks suspicious, are you trying to use forwarding references on `std::function<void(const T&)>` (`std::forward`)?

Comment: @Holt: Yeah. Wrong? Should I be taking by value instead? I don't really know _why_ I'm `std::forward`ing to be quite honest.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you cannot use forwarding reference on non-top level template parameter, you are always taking the function by rvalue I think (try passing a variable of type `std::function` to your `expect`). Note that for whatever obscure reason, passing a named lambda `auto l = [] (const Foo&) { }` does work...

Comment: @Holt: Hmm yeah okay I'll take it by value and just `std::move` where appropriate. FWIW, that solution _was_ working (at least on 4.8.5 lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closer look at the GodBolt interface shows that "4.8.2 x86_64" is actually 4.8.5 (and "4.8.1 x86_64" reproduces), so this would appear to be a simple GCC bug after all (though I can't see it on Bugzilla).

I'll just go with the reordering workaround then, keeping the variadic argument to the right.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know "why" but it works if you invert both declaration:

```
#include <functional>

struct Foo {};

template <typename... T>
void expect(
  std::function<void(const T&)>&&... onSuccess,
  const time_t timeout,
  std::function<void()>&& onExpiry
)
{ 
}

template <typename... T>
void expect(std::function<void(const T&)>&&... onSuccess)
{

    expect<T...>(
        std::forward<std::function<void(const T&)>>(onSuccess)...,
        0,
        [](){}
    );
}

int main()
{
    expect<Foo>([=](const Foo&) {}, 42u, [=](){});
    expect<Foo, Foo>([=](const Foo&) {}, [=](const Foo&) {}, 42u, [=](){});
    expect<Foo, Foo>([=](const Foo&) {}, [=](const Foo&) {});
}
```

Comment: That magically fixes the testcase above. Sadly, it doesn't fix my real code, which -- having made this change -- apparently now has a similar problem elsewhere. But that's not your fault. I'll continue down this line of reasoning...

Comment: lol, hilarious, seems to break if there's another such function declared elsewhere beforehand ... even in a completely different scope and a different name. Say, a member of `struct Bar`. Guess variadics are just kinda broken in 4.8.1/2

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Magic never works well in programming unfortunately... ;) Could you provide a test case where this fails?

Comment: [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f0f2fa5b4e4b3a3) though you'll have to copy/paste into GodBolt obvs. BTW I took out the forwarding on your recommendation :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, typo... use this instead http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4585b45ac01f32f7

Comment: The only reliable way I'm finding is to keep the variadic argument last in all cases